# Change all application design to support RTL

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, right-to-left

In my application i want to support RTL Layout direction to support Arabic language. using following function

```
  private void forceArabicLanguage() {
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
    Configuration newConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
      newConfig.setLocale(locale);
    else
      newConfig.locale = locale;
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  }
```

I can change my configuration and read strings based on language and the layout changed successfully after add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to `Application in Manifest` till now  every thing work correctly but in my design xml i set gravity for each item to be right or left before want to support RTL so design now not full changed based on gravity.

My question is : there is any configuration to change all gravity or change all xml to be RTL direction without create another resource layout under values-ar? or must change it? thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 'left' and 'right' as gravity, use 'start' and 'end'.
This will take RTL support into account. In LTR, start will be left. In RTL (arabic), start will be right.

Note that these gravities were added in api 17.
To support earlier versions you should:
- In XML define both start *and* left.
- Programatically use GravityCompat.START and GravityCompat.END